# Can't set CopyFromRecordset results to Date or Number

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to import a data set from Access 2010 into Excel using `Range.CopyFromRecordset`.  There are some fields in the query where some of the values have been cast to dates or numbers, e.g.:

```
iif(isdate([Install Date]),cdate([Install Date]),[Install Date]) 
AS [Install Date (cast)],
iif(isnumeric([Feature Number]),cdbl([Feature Number]),[Feature Number]) 
AS [Feature Number (cast)]
```

Here is the code that I am using to generate a worksheet with this data:

```
Private Sub createRSSheet(db As DAO.Database, rsName As String, sheetName As String)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fldCtr As Long
Dim columnRng As Range


'get recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(rsName)

'add worksheet
Set sht = bk.Sheets.Add
sht.Name = sheetName

'import recordset to worksheet
sht.Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'iterate through fields
For fldCtr = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    sht.Cells(1, fldCtr + 1) = rs.Fields(fldCtr).Name

    'check if field is a date field
    If InStr(UCase(rs.Fields(fldCtr).Name), "DATE") > 0 Then

        'format column as date
        Set columnRng = sht.Cells(1, fldCtr + 1)
        columnRng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    'check if field is number cast
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(rs.Fields(fldCtr).Name), "(CAST)") > 0 Then

        'format column as number
        Set columnRng = sht.Cells(1, fldCtr + 1)
        columnRng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, when this sub runs, the number columns are all still formatted as text, and the date columns are still treated as strings--when I apply an autofilter, the filter lists each individual date instead of grouping them by month and year.

How can I get these columns to end up with the desired format?

Comment: Sample data may be helpful...

Comment: Try moving the `CopyFromRecordset` call to after the `For fldCtr` loop

Comment: @barrowc, I tried that but the behavior didn't change.  i solved it using the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
'check if field is a date field
If InStr(UCase(rs.Fields(fldCtr).Name), "DATE") > 0 Then

    'format column as date
    Set columnRng = sht.Cells(1, fldCtr + 1)
    columnRng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    'refresh column values with new formatting
    columnrng.EntireColumn.Value=columnrng.EntireColumn.Value


'check if field is number cast
ElseIf InStr(UCase(rs.Fields(fldCtr).Name), "(CAST)") > 0 Then

    'format column as number
    Set columnRng = sht.Cells(1, fldCtr + 1)
    columnRng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = 0

    'refresh column values with new formatting
    columnrng.EntireColumn.Value=columnrng.EntireColumn.Value
End If
```